# CCSpriteBatchNode: Does the Child of Child receive drawing performance gains?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a `CCSpriteBatchNode` with a configuration like this:

```
CCSpriteBatchNode
    ChildA1
        ChildB1
        ChildB2
        ....
        ChildB999
    ChildA2
    ChildA3
    ...
```

Where all children (ChildA1,ChildB1,ChildA2...) are `CCSprite` objects.  The `CCSpriteBatchNode` and all children but `ChildA1` is created via:

```
[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"FileName.png"];
```

`ChildA1` is created like this:

```
// Create Parent Sprite
CCSprite* childA1 = [[CCSprite alloc] init];
childA1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(37.5,37.5);
childA1.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
[batchNode addChild:childA1 z:0 tag:1];

// Add Child Sprites
[childA1 addChild:childB1 z:0 tag:1];
[childA1 addChild:childB2 z:0 tag:1];
[childA1 addChild:childB3 z:0 tag:1];
// Continue adding childB4-childB999
```

Note: This renders just fine, and I see the output I expect, where `childB1`'s position is relative to `childA1`, and moving `childA1` results in `childB1` moving.

My question is this: Will I see a performance gain in the drawing each of `childB1`-`childB999`?  From what I understand, the `CCSpriteBatchNode` optimizes the drawing of all children within a `CCSpriteBatchNode` by  drawing all its child `CCSprites` together.  Does this also apply to the children of those `CCSprites`?

For those who want to know why I'm doing this:
There are many layers within this game and grouping `CCSprites` inside of a `CCSprite` within a `CCSpriteBatchNode` allows me to manipulate a group of `CCSprites` by manipulating only the parent of that group of sprites.

Comment: AFAIK, yes. If you are using cocos2.0 or higher, check the number of draws figure, add some children, it should not increase : ie the batch node consumes a single draw call per texture added (as opposed as 'per sprite added'). Dont know if you are ARC'ing, but if you are not you are probably leaking childA1 as written (that constructor does not return an autoreleased object).

Comment: I agree with YvesLeBrog.. If you talk about Texture Memory for Cocos2d, its loaded per image or texture. Once a texture is loaded into memory, neither it takes memory nor time to load it again which results in improvement in performance for the game. Regarding memory consumed by you variables, I don't think this is ideal way as CCSprite instances are autorelease in its class itself. So we need not worry about their memory consumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is, yes, `CCSpriteBatchNode` will make one draw call for all child nodes including all indirect descendants.

However, whether or not this performs better than using regular `CCSprites` depends on how often you are modifying the sprites.  When you use a `CCSpriteBatchNode`, every time you modify a sprite, it will need to recalculate the texture atlas quad coordinates for that sprite and all its children using the CPU rather than the GPU.  For your example, if you move the position of `ChildA1`, the coordinates for `ChildB1` to `ChildB999` will be recalculated before the next frame is rendered.  In most applications, the reduction in openGL draw calls out weights the cost of the extra calculations, as draw calls are relatively expensive, but ultimately it will depend on your application and how it uses the sprites -- so I would suggest taking actual measurements for your application if this is a performance bottleneck.